# "unfortunately API demo has stopped" - PhoneGap unaltered HelloWorld app does not run

Tags: eclipse, cordova

---

Note: I am a total Cordova/PhoneGap newbie (former ActionScript programmer)

---

Hello. I am trying to run this 101 tutorial:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

It works fine until the **Deploy to Emulator** section, where I run this line:

```
$ cordova emulate android
```

My emulator opens, but just displays the following message:

```
Unfortunately, API demo has stopped
```

I have read all the posts here with "unfortunately API demo has stopped" in them, to no avail sadly. Being 100% new to this, I would have absolutely no idea where to start debugging.

---

If it helps:

1. When the emulator starts, the "phone" shows a screen that reads "Connect your charger" which I get past by clicking the "menu" hardware button, at which point the "Unfortunately..." message appears; and
2. there is no HelloWorld.xml file.

Comment: have you tried opening the emulator and virtual devise first? then run your build?

Comment: Hi Neil. Well in order to run the emulator I need to type "Android" into the Terminal (am on OSX) and then open it via the Android SDK Manager app during which that Terminal line will be in session, and the in order to run the HelloWorld app I need to type "cordova emulate android" into the Terminal. The only way to type this is to ctrl + c out of the existing "android" Terminal session... which will close the emulator!

Comment: you can open a new terminal window, so you don't have to ctrl + c to type the new command

Comment: Hi J Cesar. If I do that, the second terminal window simply opens a second emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FIXED IT!!!

config.xml was missing this line:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```